# Print all the tokens in the file that are labelled with the morphological tag

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, file, morphological-analysis

I want to print all the tokens which are labellad with the morphological tag in a file. So far I wrote the code shown below.

```
def index(filepath, string):

    import re
    pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+)+')
    StringList = []
    StringList.append(string)

    with open(filepath) as f:
        for lineno, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
            words = set(m.group(1) for m in pattern.finditer(line))
            matches = [keyword for keyword in StringList if keyword in words]
            if matches:
                result = "{:<15} {}".format(','.join(matches), lineno)
                print(result)

    StringList.clear()



index('deneme.txt', '+Noun')
```

The output is like this, I can find the Noun in the token and the line number but can't print the part which I wanted. I only want the word part which is before + sign.

```
Noun            1
Noun            2
Noun            3
Noun            4
Noun            5
Noun            6
Noun            7
```

The lines in my file is like this:

```
Türkiye+Noun ,+Punc terörizm+Noun+Gen ve+Conj kitle+Noun imha+Noun silah+Noun+A3pl+P3sg+Gen küresel+Adj düzey+Noun+Loc oluş+Verb+Caus+PastPart+P3sg tehdit+Noun+Gen boyut+Noun+P3sg karşı+Adj+P3sg+Loc ,+Punc tüm+Det ülke+Noun+A3pl+Gen yay+Verb+Pass+Inf2+Gen önle+Verb+Pass+Inf2+P3sg hedef+Noun+A3pl+P3sg+Acc paylaş+Verb+PastPart+P3pl ,+Punc daha+Noun güven+Noun+With ve+Conj istikrar+Noun+With bir+Num dünya+Noun düzen+Noun+P3sg için+PostpPCGen birlik+Noun+Loc çaba+Noun göster+Verb+PastPart+P3pl bir+Num aşama+Noun+Dat gel+Verb+Pass+Inf2+P3sg+Acc samimi+Adj ol+Verb+ByDoingSo arzula+Verb+Prog2+Cop .+Punc 
Türkiye+Noun+Gen ekonomik+Adj ve+Conj insani+Adj potansiyel+Noun+P3sg ,+Punc güç+Noun+With savun+Verb+Inf2 kapasite+Noun+P3sg ,+Punc ulus+Noun+A3pl+InBetween çatış+Verb+Inf2+A3pl+Gen önle+Verb+Pass+Inf2+P3sg ve+Conj barış+Noun+P3sg inşa+Noun çaba+Noun+A3pl+P3sg+Dat aktif+Adj katılım+Noun+P3sg+Gen yanısıra+PostpPCGen ,+Punc fark+Noun+With kültür+Noun ve+Conj gelenek+Noun+A3pl+Dat ait+PostpPCDat seçkin+Adj özellik+Noun+A3pl+Acc birleş+Verb+Caus+PresPart bir+Num bünye+Noun+Dat sahip+Noun ol+Verb+Inf2+P3sg ,+Punc kendi+Pron+P3sg bölge+Noun+P3sg+Loc ve+Conj öte+Noun+P3sg+Loc önem+Noun+With rol+Noun oyna+Verb+Inf2+P3sg+Acc sağla+Verb+Fut değer+Noun+With özellik+Noun+A3pl+Cop .+Punc 
Türkiye+Noun ,+Punc bu+Det önem+Noun+With katkı+Noun+Acc yap+Verb+Able+Inf1 için+PostpPCGen yeterli+Adj donanım+Noun+P3sg haiz+Adj bir+Num ülke+Noun+Cop ve+Conj gelecek+Noun nesil+Noun+A3pl için+PostpPCGen daha+Noun i+Noun+Acc bir+Num dünya+Noun oluş+Verb+Caus+Inf1 amaç+Noun+P3sg+Ins ,+Punc dost+Noun+A3pl+P3pl ve+Conj müttefik+Adj+A3pl+P3sg+Ins yakın+Noun bir+Num biçim+Noun+Loc çalış+Verb+Inf2+Dat devam+Noun et+Verb+Fut+Cop .+Punc 
Ab+Noun ile+PostpPCNom gümrük+Noun Alan+Noun+P3sg+Loc+Rel kurumsal+Adj ilişki+Noun+A3pl 
club+Noun toplantı+Noun+A3pl+P3sg 
Türkiye+Noun -+Punc At+Noun gümrük+Noun işbirlik+Noun+P3sg komite+Noun+P3sg ,+Punc Ankara+Noun Anlaşma+Noun+P3sg+Gen 6+Num madde+Noun+P3sg uyar+Verb+When ortaklık+Noun rejim+Noun+P3sg+Gen uygula+Verb+Pass+Inf2+P3sg+Acc ve+Conj geliş+Verb+Inf2+P3sg+Acc sağla+Verb+Inf1 üzere+PostpPCNom ortaklık+Noun Konsey+Noun+P3sg+Gen 2+Num /+Punc 69+Num sayılı+Adj karar+Noun+P3sg ile+Conj teknik+Noun komite+Noun mahiyet+Noun+P3sg+Loc kur+Verb+Pass+Narr+Cop .+Punc 
club+Noun toplantı+Noun+A3pl+P3sg 
nispi+Adj 
nisbi+Adj 
görece+Adj+With 
izafi+Adj 
obur+Adj
```

I want to get the tokens forexample when i write a tag.
Forexample when I write +Adj I want to get all the tokens which include +Adj (nispi, izafi .... (forexample)).

Comment: can it be that `+` sign will be between your words like `++Punc`?

Comment: No, they are used for adding morphological tag to the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your concept how to use regexes needs some improvement.

Note that each input line contains a number of "tokens", e.g. `terörizm+Noun+Gen`.
As you can see, it contains:

- the first word - actual word from text,
- a number of *classification symbols*, each preceded with a `+` char.

So:

- each line should be split into tokens, on a sequence of blank chars,
- each token should be split into words, on `+` char,
- the first from these words is the "actual" word,
- the remaining words (without `+`) are classification symbols.

A good habit it to strip the terminating blank chars (at least `\n`).

Note also that your code contains `StringList`, so you are aware of the
case that this function may look for **one or more of multiple**
classification words.

I programmed it a slightly different way:

- The second parameter (`lookFor`) is a **list** of words, which is
  converted into a set (`lookForSet`).
- The set of words (result of splitting of a token, minus the first word)
  is also converted into a set.

The decision whether to print a word (the first word from a token) is based on
whether at least one of its classification symbols can be found in `lookForSet`.
To put it another way - whether `lookForSet` and `wordSet` have some
common elements (set intersection).

So the whole script can look like below:

```
import re

def index(fileName, lookFor):
    lookForSet = set(lookFor)  # Set of classification symbols to look for
    pat1 = re.compile(r'\s+')  # Regex to split line into tokens
    pat2 = re.compile(r'\+')   # Regex to split a token into words
    with open(fileName) as f:
        for lineNo, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
            line = line.rstrip()
            tokens = pat1.split(line)
            for token in tokens:
                words = pat2.split(token)
                word1 = words.pop(0)  # Initial word
                wordSet = set(words)  # Classification words
                commonWords = lookForSet.intersection(wordSet)
                if commonWords:
                    print("{:3}: {:<15} {}".format(lineNo, word1, ', '.join(commonWords)))

index('lines.txt', ['Noun', 'Gen'])
```

A piece of output from it, for my input data (slightly shortened version of your)
is like below:

```
1: Türkiye         Noun
1: terörizm        Noun, Gen
1: kitle           Noun
1: imha            Noun
2: Türkiye         Noun, Gen
2: potansiyel      Noun
```

It contains:

- the number of source line,
- the fist word of a token,
- which classification words from `lookFor` have been found in this token.

Comment: Thanks for all the information you gave, It was very helpful to get the idea but I got some problem which I couldn't solve. Your code works perfectly but when I type Noun+Gen forexample it isn't working. I also want my code to work with more than one words. It is okay when I only look for Noun or Gen but data includes tags like Noun+Gen. So I also want to get them as well.

Comment: The source of the problem is that you pass 2 classification symbols as a **single string**. Note that the second parameter should be passed as a **list of strings**, in this case: `['Noun', 'Gen']`. If you want to call this function with a **single** classification symbol, pass also a list of strings, this time containing a single string.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting on `\w+` removed the `+` part from what you are looking for, so I split on the spaces in between instead. Then it was just a case of wrestling the `for` and `in` into the right order for the list comprehension.

```
def index(filepath, string):
    StringList = [string]

    with open(filepath) as f:
        for lineno, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
            words = line.split(' ')
            matches = [word for keyword in StringList for word in words if keyword in word]
            if matches:
                result = "{:<15} {}".format(','.join(matches), lineno)
                print(result)


index('deneme.txt', '+Adj')
```

Which leads to the result:

```
küresel+Adj,karşı+Adj+P3sg+Loc,samimi+Adj 1
ekonomik+Adj,insani+Adj,aktif+Adj,seçkin+Adj 2
yeterli+Adj,haiz+Adj,müttefik+Adj+A3pl+P3sg+Ins 3
kurumsal+Adj    4
sayılı+Adj      6
nispi+Adj       8
nisbi+Adj       9
görece+Adj+With 10
izafi+Adj       11
obur+Adj        12
```

I removed the line `StringList.clear()` as it somehow gave an error, though.

Works with both Python 2.7 and 3.6+, although the extended Unicode characters in your text will throw off the alignment using 2.7.